# R: sampling using dbinom(y-0:200)

Tags: programming

In `R`:

I have a sample (`y`) of length `1e4`.

`y = sample(0:200, 1e4, replace = TRUE)`

I have plugged this sample into:

`dbinom(y-x,100,0.3)`

However, I would like to gather samples from this function but simulate for `x` values from `0:200`

i.e

`x = 0:200`

For e.g. the first iteration will be `1e4` samples of `dbinom(y-0,100,0.3)` which will produce `1e4` samples then the next iteration will be `dbinom(y-1,100,0.3)` etc up until `x = 200.`

This is for going to be used in getting the `M = max(f(y)/h(y))` for accept-reject envelope method however since my `f(y)` is discrete I would like to sample for each integer value of x = 0:200 and then get the max from there.

However, I am unsure as to how to approach this as I am new to `R`.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I think this should be posted on Stack Overflow (https://stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 0):

```
idx <- 0:200
y <- sample(idx, 1e4, replace = TRUE)
lapply(idx, function(x) {
  message('x = ', x)
  dbinom(y - x, 100, 0.3)  
})
```